# Writing multipart features in INTERLIS using FME

Tags: fme-form, multipart, interlis

Trying to export a geopackage into an .xtf I run into the following problem:

*unexpected geometry type COM.safe.fmeobjects.FMEMultiCurve*

The .ili looks like this (simplified for posting here)

```
CLASS G (ABSTRACT) =
  Identifikator          : MANDATORY 1000 .. 9999;
  Name                   : MANDATORY TEXT*250;
UNIQUE Identifikator;
END G;

CLASS G_Linie EXTENDS G =
  Geometrie              : MANDATORY POLYLINE WITH (STRAIGHTS) VERTEX GeometryCHLV95_V1.Coord2;
END G;
```

GeometryCHLV95_V1 is a swiss base modul which you can find [here](http://models.geo.admin.ch/CH/CHBase_Part1_GEOMETRY_V1.ili):
It contains among other things:

```
Coord2 = COORD
  2460000.000 .. 2870000.000 [m] {CHLV95[1]},
  1045000.000 .. 1310000.000 [m] {CHLV95[2]},
  ROTATION 2 -> 1;
```

I assume the problems occur because the geopackage contains a multipart-Polyline and POLYLINE does not allow this.

I tried the following:

If I use an FME **Deaggregator** I run into problems because there is a UNIQUE identificator in the class.

I also tried the class Multiline

```
STRUCTURE MultiLine =
  Lines: BAG {1..*} OF LineStructure;
END MultiLine;
```

also part of the base model.
I applied it like this:

```
CLASS G (ABSTRACT) =
  Identifikator          : MANDATORY 1000 .. 9999;
  Name                   : MANDATORY TEXT*250;
UNIQUE Identifikator;
END G;

CLASS G_Linie EXTENDS G =
  Geometrie              : GeometryCHLV95_V1.MultiLine;
END Gefahrenquelle_Linie;
```

unlike the first 2 tries, this translation runs without errors, but the resulting .xtf file does not contain any *Geometrie* attribute on the written instances of G.

How do I get mulitpart features in my class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second model is ok:

```
CLASS G_Linie EXTENDS G =
  Geometrie              : GeometryCHLV95_V1.MultiLine;
END Gefahrenquelle_Linie;
```

But you have to move the geometry from the FME features into the list attribute. See [here](https://www.ili2fme.ch/posts/2014/multilinewrite.html) for an example

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this seems to work. But I cannot be 100% sure. If I load the .xtf into QGIS using the INTERLIS plugin, I only see parts of those lines. However the .xtf files shows points that are not displayed in QGIS. I will assume that this is a seperate issue with the plugin and accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a solution without using the PythonCaller.
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).